# Код для создания тг бота, токен тг и api есть, выдает ошибку "AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'start_polling' в коде представлено

Tags: python, telegram-bot, type-error

[image: подскажите, что не так с кодом]
подскажите что не так с кодом, делал по гайду
import openai

```
from aiogram import Bot, types
from aiogram.dispatcher import Dispatcher
from aiogram.utils import executor

telegram_token = "Токен от телеграмм бота"
openai.api_key = "Токен от OpenAI ChatGPT"

bot = Bot(telegram_token)
dp = Dispatcher(bot)

@dp.message_handler()
async def send(message: types.Message):
    response = openai.Completion.create(
        model="text-davinci-003",
        prompt=message.text,
        temperature=0.9,
        max_tokens=2000,
        top_p=1.0,
        frequency_penalty=0.0,
        presence_penalty=0.6,
    )
    await message.answer(response['choices'][0]['text'])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    executor.start_polling(dp, skip_updates=Tru
```

e)

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! [пожалуйста, не добавляйте код/данные/текст ошибок картинками.](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12119)

Comment: https://docs.aiogram.dev/en/latest/#simple-usage

Comment: А код текстом приложить не хотите?

Comment: исправил, помогите пожалуйста